# Mongodb Index & search for comma separated value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-indexes

I have structure like below

```
{
  "name": "",
  "age": 35,
  "hobbies": "gardening, skiing, horse riding, soccer",
  "Address": {
    "addrline 1": "",
    "addrline 2": "",
    "City": "",
    "Zip": ""
  }
}
```

Would like to search based on hobby. e.g. for input "skiing" should return this Document. I have around 80k records. What would be the best Indexing strategy for "hobbies" element so that it can return result fast.

Do I have to search "hobbies" only by string based regex pattern or is there any other technique for faster data retrieval?

Answer (score 5):

A better design would be to store hobbies as an array

```
 "hobbies": ["gardening", "skiing", "horse riding", "soccer"]
```

Then , you can use $in query to match any one or multiple hobbies.
Create an index on the hobbies key for faster querying.

Comment: Totally agree with @DhruvPathak , maybe you can run a script or command and turn the comma separated value to an array, Then add a multikey index on hobbies, that way you won't have to do a regex query, regex are not efficient in using indexes for faster search.